# Why does raster plot "north" as "south"?

Tags: r, gis, raster

I have no problems using the raster package when I stay within the confines of the provided functions but when I go off-piste and manually mess with the internals I get into trouble.  In this example I am trying to change raster matrix element but is seems that "south" gets turned into "north" when when plotting?  What is happening?  Thanks.

```
    # test raster plotting
    library(raster)
    #> Loading required package: sp
    
    m1 <- matrix(1,nrow=10,ncol=10)
    
    r1 <- raster::raster(m1)
    r1 <- setExtent(r1,c(1,10,1,10))
    r1
    #> class      : RasterLayer 
    #> dimensions : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
    #> resolution : 0.9, 0.9  (x, y)
    #> extent     : 1, 10, 1, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    #> crs        : NA 
    #> source     : memory
    #> names      : layer 
    #> values     : 1, 1  (min, max)
    # looks as we expect, all 1
    plot(r1)
```

[image: plot of raster with all ones]

```
    # set first, bottom, most southerly row, to zero
    m1[1,] = 0
    
    r2 <- raster::raster(m1)
    r2 <- setExtent(r2,extent(r1))
    r2
    #> class      : RasterLayer 
    #> dimensions : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
    #> resolution : 0.9, 0.9  (x, y)
    #> extent     : 1, 10, 1, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    #> crs        : NA 
    #> source     : memory
    #> names      : layer 
    #> values     : 0, 1  (min, max)
    plot(r2)
```

[image: raster showing north as zero]

```
    # top, most northerly row is displayed as zero
    Created on 2022-02-19 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Comment: Hi Art, all is fine: cell numbers start at 1 in the upper left corner, and increase from left to right, and then from top to bottom. So when you run `m1[1, ] <- 0`, you set the first row from the top of the image with zeros, exactly the result you get. Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. What confused me is that I changed row "1" in the matrix and it's labeled 10 on the plot.  So, if I want to manually change the matrix I have to remember that up is down.  I guess that's just the way it is.

Comment: The first row in the matrix is the first row in the raster so up is up. "10" is a coordinate, not a row number. And 10 is further North than 0.